# Infinite intersection of closed subsets

Tags: general-topology

Given $V_{n+1}\subseteq V_n$ can one say that 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}V_n$$

?????????

$V_n$ are closed if that matters.

EDIT: Sorry for being unclear.

$V_n$ is a set generated by means of some algorithm that takes $n$ and output a set of points from a given superset. The only condition of the algorithm is that each subsequent set needs to be a subset of all the previous ones.

For example:

$$V_n = \left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: What is your definition of limit here?

Comment: What do you mean by a limit of sets?

Comment: Indeed, this is a consequence of the usual definition of limit of sets (and it doesn't matter if the sets are closed or not).

Comment: Your example is not closed.

Comment: Relevant: [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit)

Answer (score 1):

One can say that. That's the definition for a limit of a monotone decreasing sequence of sets. That limit is by definition the intersection of all the sets.

Analogically, if you have a monotone increasing sequence of sets, you define its limit to be the union of all sets.

For these two definitions it does not matter if the sets (from these sequences) are closed or not.